# Converting a decimal * 3 resulting in currency?

Tags: c#

```
        TimeSpan span1 = TimeSpan.FromHours(dtmIn.Value.Hour);
        TimeSpan span2 = TimeSpan.FromHours(dtmOut.Value.Hour);
        TimeSpan span3 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dtmIn.Value.Minute);
        TimeSpan span4 = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(dtmOut.Value.Minute);
        TimeSpan span5 = span2.Subtract(span1) + span4.Subtract(span3);
        if (dtmOut.Value.Hour < dtmIn.Value.Hour)
            MessageBox.Show("Time Out can not be less");
        lblTotal.Text = span5.TotalHours.ToString("#.00");
```

How would I take span5 and multiply it by 3?

Comment: would `Timespan timesThree = span5.Add(span5).Add(span5);` be cheating?

Comment: How is a TimeSpan a currency?

Comment: You can convert TimeSpan into fractions of an hour; therefore using this to multiply by an hourly rate.

Comment: @John: That's still not "a currency", but rather an "amount of money *in a specific currency*", but I get your point.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. I am a fairly new programmer.

Answer (score 2):

```
    lblTotal.Text = (span5.TotalHours * 3).ToString("#.00");
```

Comment: Thank you. I am a fairly new programmer.